# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in InceptionResNetV2 Keras

Tags: python, keras

i'm try to download Inception ResNet V2 network on a Google Colab project but an error appears. And i don't know what to do.

I'm try

`base_model = tf.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)`

and the error is TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.  how are you importing tf.keras?

Answer (score 3):

[`tf.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/inception_resnet_v2) is a module. I think you need [`tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/InceptionResNetV2)

and as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/InceptionResNetV2):

```py
tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(
    include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None,
    pooling=None, classes=1000, classifier_activation='softmax', **kwargs
)
```